# Does the fluctuation-dissipation (FD) relation $\sigma_E^2=k_BT^2C_V$ arise as a special case of the FD theorem?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, non-equilibrium, fluctuation-dissipation

The classical [fluctuation-dissipation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem) states that the power spectral density $S_{\eta\eta}(\omega)$ of a classical random variable $\eta(t)$ is given by $$S_{\eta\eta}(\omega)=\frac{2k_BT}{\omega}{\rm Im}\left[\chi(\omega)\right]\tag{1}$$ where $\chi(\omega)$ is the Fourier ransform of the response function $\chi(t)$ called the generalized susceptibility.

[The Johnson-Nyquist noise in a resistor arises as a special case of this theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem#Thermal_noise_in_a_resistor) Similarly, the relation between the strength of the random force acting on a Brownian particle and the damping can also arise as an application of this theorem.

However, there is another fluctuation-dissipation relation (See Eq.$1.27$ of [David Tong's lecture notes on Statistical Physics](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html), and the paragraph following it) in statistical mechanics: the thermal fluctuation in energy is given by$$\sigma_E^2=k_BT^2C_V\tag{2}$$ where $c_v$ is the heat capacity at constant volume.  Can Eq.$(2)$ be derived from Eq.$(1)$ as a special case of it? I asked a similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/333317/can-we-take-sigma2-n-frac-kappa-t-beta-vn2-to-be-an-example-of-the-flu?rq=1) but it does not answer how relation $(2)$ could arise from a more general relation.

Comment: Mm... I wouldn't call (2) a fluctuation-dissipation relationship because $C_V$ does not represent a dissipation in the same sense the susceptibility does.

Comment: In that case, is there a general relation in linear response theory, from which (2) arises as a consequence? @MassimoOrtolano

Comment: The latter is the $\omega = 0$ case of the former.